# Character facing z direction after stop moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I have a problem in keeping the character facing the same direction he was facing its always turn to the z direction of the world coordinate I hope to find way to fix this problem.

I tried to stop this with using `Quaternion.LookRotation()` and `Vector3.RotateToward()` but still when stop he rotate in idle animation to the world z direction.

```
public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 _CharacterDirection;
    Quaternion _CharacterRotation=Quaternion.identity;
    Animator _CharacterAnim;
    Rigidbody _CharacterRigidbody;
    public float TurnSpeed;

    void Start()
    {
        _CharacterAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _CharacterRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CharacterMovement();
    }

    void CharacterMovement()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        _CharacterDirection.Set(h, 0, v);
        _CharacterDirection.Normalize();

        bool _IsHorizontalChange = !Mathf.Approximately(h, 0f);
        bool _IsVerticalChange = !Mathf.Approximately(v, 0);
        bool _IsWalking = _IsHorizontalChange || _IsVerticalChange;
        _CharacterAnim.SetBool("IsWalking", _IsWalking);

         Vector3 _DesairdForward = Vector3.RotateTowards(Vector3.forward, _CharacterDirection, TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        _CharacterRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_DesairdForward);


        _CharacterRigidbody.MovePosition(_CharacterRigidbody.position + _CharacterDirection * Time.deltaTime);
        _CharacterRigidbody.MoveRotation(_CharacterRotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing a Vector3.forward every fixed update  Vector3.forward is the same as the world z forward.  you should be using his transform.forward.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html  (So you are going to get a vector every update that tries to rotate a vector3.forward to a 0,0,0 vector when you are not moving, which wille turn into the world forward.)

Comment: thank you for your reply this answer solved my problem thank you very much